# Architecture for Flash player analytics system

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, analytics

I have a Flash player, and I want to add a simple analytics system to it. I want it to track how many times a video was watched, the viewers IP address, etc.

I really don't know how to design this kind of system that has so many database writes (expected to be around 5 metrics for a player, for 100 people/sec).

That's why I'm appealing to you, in order to consult the architecture of the service before running into it.

It would be great to have some tips, and guidance of how I should build it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Google Analytics using the Flash API. It's pretty simple to implement and it's free to use.

Comment: I had that in mind, but I really want my own system -- mostly because there are some metrics I want to implement in the future that Google Analytics don't provide details about.